# Running a PowerShell scriptblock at the end of an unattended WDS deployment

Tags: powershell, wds

During an unattended installation with WDS, I need to run a script on a share just at the end of pass **7 oobeSystem**.

I use the **FirstLogonCommands / SynchronousCommand** option and provide this command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Maximized -NoProfile -Command {New-SmbMapping -LocalPath z: -RemotePath \\10.10.10.5\Share -Persistent $false -UserName user -Password password; z:\script.ps1}
```

It opens the PowerShell console, but displays the scriptblock at the top of this window before displaying the command prompt, and unfortunately does not execute the scriptblock.

I tried to introduce a sleep before, but it doesn't change the result.
Here is an example:

[image: pow]

How can I fix this?

Comment: From `powershell -?`: _To write a string that runs a Windows PowerShell command, use the format: `"& {<command>}"`_

Comment: I already tried that but I will try again. Give some time...

Comment: Please note that  angle brackets `<` and `>` (or _Less-Than Sign_ and _Greater-Than Sign_) here are metasymbols, not a part of  resultant code. Hence, you can use something like the following: `… -Command "& {Start-Sleep 30; Get-Childitem .}"`.

Comment: It appears that `"& {Get-Childitem -Path C:\}"` works fine, but `"& {New-SmbMapping -LocalPath z: -RemotePath \\10.10.10.5\Share; z:\script.ps1}"`doesn't even display a PowerShell console at all...

Comment: My bad for the former partial copy/paste because I though some part was irrelevant... `"& {New-SmbMapping -LocalPath z: -RemotePath \\10.10.10.5\Share -UserName User -Password password}"` worsk fine. However, `"& {New-SmbMapping -LocalPath z: -RemotePath \\10.10.10.5\Share -Persistent $false -UserName User -Password password}"` does not open any PowerShell window. Maybe the $ sign is the problem here... Trying some more dichotomy...

Comment: It's not the dollar sign as `powershell -command "& {$false.GetType().Name}"` returns `Boolean` as expected. Maybe `-Password 'password'`?

Comment: You precedent guess was good. I replaced $false with 0 and this part is now working. Just trying to figure out why when I add the second part `; z:\script.ps1` it is preventing the PowerShell console from opening... Maybe you are right and it's because there is something behind the password and the password must be quoted...

Comment: To be sure it's not a quoting issue I've put the -Persistent parameter at the end and `"& {New-SmbMapping -LocalPath z: -RemotePath \\10.10.10.5\Share -UserName User -Password password  -Persistent 0}"` is working fine. But as soon as I add a `; z:\script.ps1` the PowerShell window doesn't open.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97302/discussion-between-josefz-and-luke).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `FirstLogonCommands` documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-firstlogoncommands) shows an [XML Example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-firstlogoncommands#xml-example) how to specify two commands to run after first logon. Modifying `CommandLine` according to your circumstances, relevant part of an `unattend.xml` could look as follows:

```
<FirstLogonCommands>
   <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
      <CommandLine>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "& {New-SmbMapping -LocalPath z: -RemotePath \\10.10.10.5\Share -UserName User -Password password -Persistent 0}"</CommandLine>
      <Description>Description_of_command1</Description>
      <Order>1</Order>
   </SynchronousCommand>
   <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
      <CommandLine>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -File z:\script.ps1</CommandLine>
      <Description>Description_of_command2</Description>
      <Order>2</Order>
   </SynchronousCommand>
</FirstLogonCommands>
```

Please note that in above code snippet the `-NoExit` parameter is removed completely and the `-WindowStyle Maximized` is changed to `-WindowStyle Hidden`, according to your statement from our previous discussion: "*I use the `-NoExit` parameter just to be sure if the command fails I can see what happened*".